# Connect to my work LAN and ADSL a the same time

Tags: router, dns, internet, routing, lan

The scenario is to connect to my company LAN and an ADSL modem at the same time.

My PC has two network cards. one is connected to internal company LAN(no Internet connection) and another is connected to ADSL modem(Internet connection). but when I want to for example open the http://hr site (local intranet site) on one tab and let's say www.google.com on another tab, one can not open! So I have to disable one Ethernet connection to be able to connect to another.

I search a lot for this issue, also I'v tried different IP route config things and it doesn't work yet.

Also DNS server of our local LAN is 10.1.2.60 and the gateway is 10.1.16.1

DNS server of modem is 192.168.1.1 and the gateway is 192.168.1.1

My IP is 10.1.16.119 (from LAN) and 192.168.1.14 (from Modem)

I believe there is a route command that I can set in my routing table to connect and use both networks.

I appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**
this is my routing table

```
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.1.16.1      10.1.16.119     20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.14     20
        10.1.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.1.16.119     21
      10.1.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.16.119    276
        10.1.16.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.1.16.119    276
      10.1.16.119  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.16.119    276
      10.1.16.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.16.119    276
    10.70.246.249  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.14     36
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.14    276
     192.168.1.14  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.14    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.14    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.16.119    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.14    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.16.119    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.14    276
===========================================================================

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : CU-VEGHI
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : tckh.ir

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8dbb:7b27:c250:da0b%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : شنبه, 21 فوريه 2015 07:57:56 ق.ظ
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : سه شنبه, 24 فوريه 2015 07:57:56 ق.ظ
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 124579913
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-A8-C2-12-00-13-46-90-5B-1E

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
                                       10.1.2.60
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : tckh.ir
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : D-Link DFE-530TX PCI Fast Ethernet Adapte
r (rev.C)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c06a:300e:1ee3:3d2f%3(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.16.119(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : شنبه, 21 فوريه 2015 07:57:48 ق.ظ
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : يكشنبه, 01 مارس 2015 07:57:48 ق.ظ
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.16.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.2.23
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50336582
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-A8-C2-12-00-13-46-90-5B-1E

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.2.60
                                       192.168.1.1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.1.2.60
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A235B2F6-C037-48D6-9670-0F5B6D704EE5}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.tckh.ir:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : tckh.ir
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5efe:10.1.16.119%19(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 671088640
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-A8-C2-12-00-13-46-90-5B-1E

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.2.60
                                       192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using both ADSL and LAN at the same time](http://superuser.com/questions/91057/using-both-adsl-and-lan-at-the-same-time)

Comment: this is different, one network is local Intranet and another is Internet from ADSL modem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is propable the routing. Normally the default gateway is the one of your company LAN. So you have to add a route to the company gateway for ALL internal networks. Then you add a new default route to the modem.
Next step is to check if the internal company DNS server can resolve external domains.
You can do that with nslookup www.ibm.com (or what ever), when you get an answer. Resolving works, if not, you can use an external dns server like 8.8.8.8, but then resolving for company servers would not work anymore.

ciao
ryder

Comment: in each network card I can set the preferred dns server and the alternate one.  what if I set in the LAN interface 10.1.2.60 for preferred and 192.168.1.1 for alternate , and vice-versa for interface connected to modem?

Answer (score 0):

There is at least 1 problem with your routing table - the netmask for your work lan is 255.255.255.0, it should be 255.255.0.0 (or maybe 255.0.0.0) - as it stands the DNS servers and gateway are outside the subnet, thus your routes are calculated incorrectly.

You may also have issues with respect of DNS servers.  If you use your company's DNS servers do they resolve addresses outside the company - if not, you may have a problem if you require zones which are not visible to the wider Internet.   There are a few ways you can handle this - probably the easiest (but least complete) way is to add entries for the desired machine in your hosts file.   (A better way would be to do run your own DNS server which routes requests as appropriate, I'd imagine BIND and DNSMasq can both do this but I've not looked at that functionality).

I also note that you have 2 default routes - 1 to your work and 1 to your Internet connection.  This explains why when you unplug the Internet connection your work connection works, the default route compensates for the incorrrect netmask.     You will want to remove the default route from the company network (or make it a higher metric = lower priority if you think you can get partial Internet connectivity through that network)

Comment: thanks.you are very clear. what is the command to change the metric(priority)?

Comment: I run "route add -p 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.1.16.119". is this good? I want to say all other traffic than 10.0.0.0 network, routed to 192.168.1.1, what is the command?

Comment: You probably don't need to do any of this - all you need to do is go into your network settings for Ethernet Adaptor (ie the LAN one), remove the default route and change the netmask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.0.0.0.      The default to route out 192.168.1.1 already exists because you have specified a default gateway.  This is what the first (non heading) line in your routing table shows.    [  I also can't help with Windows commands as I don't use that ]